# Making a gallery form in Xamarin Form

Tags: c#, json, xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am making a photo gallery that takes JSON of an image name from an url. Using list form really dont give a good UX so i am planning to change in grid form. try some code i found in stackoverflow. The problem is i try to create an array binding so that as the number of photo increase in the database the app will add a new grid for it and display it.

```
<Grid x:Name="grid">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding Images[0].MyImageUrl}" />
        <Image Grid.Column="1" Source="{Binding Images[1].MyImageUrl}" />
        <Image Grid.Column="2" Source="{Binding Images[2].MyImageUrl}" />
    </Grid>
```

this is in the XAML format now i am trying to create a cs that bind with this where will automatically create a grid file to display the image from the JSON file. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: You probably need to build your grid in code if you want it to expand based on the number of images

Comment: Jason do you know how to write it in code xaml or cs code ?

Answer (score 0):

`Grid` does not have a property like `ItemsSource`. So you will need to at least Add the images programatically.

```
protected override void OnAppearing ()
{
   base.OnAppearing();

   // Create cols for each img
   for(int col = 0; col < Images.Length; ++col){
       grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinitions { Width = new GridLenght(1, GridUnitType.Star)});
   }
   // Populate grid
   for(int col = 0; col < Images.Length; ++col){
       grid.Children.Add(new Image { source = Images[col] },0,col);
   }
}
```

If you want to do everything in XAML. Use [FlowListView](https://github.com/daniel-luberda/DLToolkit.Forms.Controls/tree/master/FlowListView)

Edit: I did 2 `for's` cause I'm not sure if you try to `Add` while you are creating the `ColumnDefinition` it will work. Anyway try it out one way or the other.